# spacing between thumbnails disappeared after using another lightbox

Tags: css, fancybox, thumbnails, lightbox, spacing

I used to have no problem with the css code i have been using.  But, after I have changed from using "Lightbox2" to "fancybox", the spacing between the thumbnails and the thumbnail border (when mouse hovering above) disappeared. What has gone wrong?

Compare the problem page after switching to using fancybox (www.lixiao-art.com/test.html ) with the page using Lightbox2 ( www.lixiao-art.com/latest.html )

This is the code I use:

---

```
body { font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: black;
margin: 0px;
background-color: RGB(181,170,128);}
*{
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-weight:normal
}


#nav {float: left;
position: fixed;
background-color: RGB(233,231,197);
text-align: left;
font-size: 11px;
color: #645630;
width: 90px;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 100px 20px 100px 30px;
border: none;
min-height: 100%;
}



#content {float: left;
margin-left: 150px;
padding: 15px 20px 10px 80px;
width: 900px;
margin-top: 0px;
border: none;
font: black;
font-size: 11px; 
}


#content a {text-decoration:underline}


h2 {height: 2em;}  


.footer {
            text-align:center; 
            padding-top: 50px;
            padding-bottom: 1em; 
            font-size: 11px;
            } 


a{text-decoration: none;
color: #645630;}
a:hover {color: red;}


* {margin: 0;}
html, body, wrapper {height: 100%;}


.ImgBorder img { border:2px solid transparent;
height:100px;
}
.ImgBorder:hover img{ border-color: white}

.ImgBorder {display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 30px 20px; }
h5{
clear:both
}

img { border: none; }
```

---

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your previous Lightbox2, each image is wrapped in an anchor

```
<a class="ImgBorder">
```

and the class `ImgBorder` has the value `margin: 30px 20px`

In your current Fancybox, you can just add this missing margin `margin: 30px 20px` to the class `fancybox` as each image is now wrapped in an anchor

```
<a class="fancybox"/>
```

As I just noticed that there doesn't seem to be any class fancybox already defined, you just have to add

```
.fancybox
{
  margin: 30px 20px;
}
```

e.g. in your global.css

**Update**: In case you also want to display the border for the fancybox-images, there are two ways of achieving this: Currently you have both lightbox versions on your test page. For the first image the border is still displayed for hover. Following CSS is taking care about that:

```
.ImgBorder img {  
  border: 2px solid transparent;  
  height: 100px;  
}  
.ImgBorder:hover img {  
   border-color:white;  
}
```

for an image markup as follows for your first image:

```
<a class="ImgBorder" rel="lightbox[gaze]" 
                     href="http://www.lixiao-art.com/work/2014/52.jpg">
    <img src="work/2014/52_t.jpg">
</a>
```

Your current fancybox-markup is like this for your second image:

```
<a href="work/2014/52.jpg" rel="group" class="fancybox">
   <img src="work/2014/52_t.jpg">
</a>
```

So all you have to add is the border and hover for the fancybox-class:

```
.fancybox img {  
  border: 2px solid transparent;  
  height: 100px;  
}  
.fancybox:hover img {  
   border-color:white;  
}
```

It's possible that there are some additional adjustments because of the CSS that fancybox uses, but it's easier if you just check this on your site as I just noticed that you're currently working on it.
At the moment your fancybox images "jump" because you added the CSS

```
.fancybox:hover
{
  border-color:white;
  margin:30px 20px;
}
```

which results in setting this margin on hover (therefore jumping then). I suggest you just try the CSS I posted above, that should work.

**Update 2** for the comments follow-up questions:
The attributes class and rel stands for the following:
`rel` (='related') is an attribute containing information for you previous lightbox. The lightbox script will just fetch the information for e.g. a big image or a link from there.
`class`: as you noticed, almost all in your css-file starts with a dot (.) followed by a name. This name is the name of the class to which the style information will apply. So `.test {color:red;}` results in displaying a text red in case it's wrapped in an element with the class test, e.g. a `<div>`: `<div class="test">This is red text</div>`.

**Update for the margins:**
To keep the margins to your images when you remove it for the :hover - the correct way to have the margins is just like that:

```
.fancybox img
{
  margin:30px 20px;
}
```

As you already have one .fancybox img in your CSS, just add this margin to it, though you can also have these selectors multiple times in a CSS file, it's better to keep the styles applying to an element together.

Comment: Thank you , defining fancybox in global.css really helps!  but, what about the border showing when the mouse is hovering above thumbnails?

Comment: @lixiao Glad that helped you. And with the border - you want the border to be displayed on hover on www.lixiao-art.com/test.html? I just checked there, it works for the 1st image because there is a different class set; it's just about one line of additional css to have it for the other images as well.

Comment: Even though things seem to work by defining fancybox in the global.css, I don't understand why I have to do it now when I use the Fancybox plugin (as in test.html) while I didn't have to do this when I used the Lightbox2 plugin (as in latest.html).

Comment: Could this be the reason?

I've noticed that with latest.html (the successful page using Lightbox2 that shows border and spacing between thumbnails), the part referring to the Lighbox is "rel=" followed by "class=ImgBorder":


<a href=http://www.lixiao-art.com/work/2014/52.jpg rel="lightbox[gaze]" class="ImgBorder"><img src="work/2014/52_t.jpg"
/></a>

Comment: But with the test.html (the problem page using FancyBox), the part referring to the FancyBox is "class=" instead of "rel=".  

Could this clash with another "class=ImgBorder" I put in the same line?  


<a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="work/2014/20.jpg" class="ImgBorder"><img src="work/2014/20_t.jpg"></a>

Comment: Excuse my layman language.  and I have no idea about what "rel" and "class" mean.

Comment: @lixiao You already checked my updated answer re different markup and CSS? In addition: it's not possible to set two class attributes like that; in case you would like to have multiple class it's done like that: class="fancybox ImgBorder". Setting class twice is not valid and leads to unexpected behavior for different browsers.

Comment: @lixiao Don't mind; I will just update my answer re "rel" and "class", and a minor problem just occuring now is that we have to avoid extended comments as stackoverflow would move this into chat, and chat isn't working for you as you need > 15 reputation for chat. In case there are still issues and we can't solve these in the comments for this question, just post a follow up question for the border-issue and we'll solve it there.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much!  You've pointed out the problem with my multiple classes, and I've fixed it accordingly like this:

```
<a class="fancybox ImgBorder" rel="group" href="work/2014/52.jpg"">
  <img src="work/2014/52_t.jpg">
</a>
```

(instead of making new definitions in my global.css)

But, a small problem shows up:  this line shows in red colour in the editor at the backoffice.  Is there a problem with this line?  but I guess I will open a new thread for this.

Thanks again!

Comment: I don't understand why the new code doesn't show up in the answer.

Comment: Glad to be of help and that you have it fixed! Sorry to ask, but it would be kind if you accept my answer by clicking the checkmark visible for you next to it, so the question will be marked as closed. Re the red line: I already noticed that there is a style for a:hover that should be deletd. And re new code and answer: that has just to do with code formatting. You just have to select the link in the text completely and click the {} icon in the icons-bar above, that cares about code formatting.

Comment: Many thanks for your detailed answers and patience.  Sorry I'm not familiar with this site.  It's my first time.

Comment: Don't mind, you're welcome. Glad that I was able to help you and in case of further issues, just post another question.

Comment: I just posted another question about the code showing red in editor.  I didn't understand what you meant about "a style for a:hover" to be deleted.  Thanks again.

Comment: That with the style for "a:hover"  is a misunderstanding; I just thought there would be something on your page displayed in red on hover and noticed that there is a selector "a:hover {color: red}" in your CSS, but it looks like this is not any problem. This selector means that every link (= <a>) on your page would be displayed in red when hovered, as you can see in the left navigation, and I guess that's ok.